# Karate: when I want to set value to $..somewhereInJsonPath I get Path must not end with a '

Tags: karate

I want to update a value of `somewhereInJsonPath` field in my JSON file.

I am using for this: `* set myBody $..someWhereInJsonPath = 'AAA'`. And when I run test I get: `Path must not end with a '.'`

But when I am using `* set myBody $..firstHere.someWhereInJsonPath = 'AAA'` it is working.

I think in first case, where we want to update first value in $.., it must working too.

**To clarify:**

For example we have JSON:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "something": 12.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
```

And when I do: $.store.book[0].something = 13 it is working.

**BUT** when I do: $..something = 13 it is not working.

Why? And how can I update this?

At http://jsonpath.com/ when I want to find $..something it is find this value. But when I use $..something in karate it is not working.

*Realted with [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54928387/karate-jsonpath-wildcards-didnt-work-or-partly-didnt-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54928387/karate-jsonpath-wildcards-didnt-work-or-partly-didnt-work_)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `set` command is not really designed for JsonPath wildcards. For example `$[*].foo` or `$..foo` are examples of wildcards. And `$[0].foo`, `$.foo` or `response.foo` are pure JS expressions.

So please stick to pure JS expressions like this. Here below, `set` is interchangeable with `eval` which is more useful in case you want to use dynamic / variables for e.g. `* eval response[foo]` where `foo` is a string.

```
* def response = { foo: { somePath: 'abc' } }
* eval response.foo.somePath = 'xyz'
* match response == { foo: { somePath: 'xyz' } }
```

If you really do need to do "bulk" updates, use a [transform function](https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms):

```
* def response = [{}, {}]
* def fun = function(x, i){ return { foo: 'bar', index: ~~(i + 1) } }
* def res = karate.map(response, fun)
* match res == [{ foo: 'bar', index: 1 }, { foo: 'bar', index: 2 }]
```

Comment: Can you relate to example that I gave, please?

Comment: I edited my question so many time to clarify it and show exactly what I need for. I didn’t change my question at he end. Sorry for editing, next time I will do it right away. I still don't understand you answer. Please relate your answer and your example to example that I gave.

Comment: @cheparsky I edited the first line of my answer. read it carefully please.

Comment: I used `* eval karate.set('ourExample','$..something', 13)` and it didn’t work. I do something wrong? I saw that example here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#eval

Comment: @cheparsky what is `ourExample` ? what is `something` ? this is getting more confusing. this is my last try: `* eval ourExample.expensive = 20`