# Karate: JsonPath wildcards didn't work or partly didn't work

Tags: jsonpath, karate

JSON file `jsonExample`:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "something": 12.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
```

I want update `"something"`. When I use:

1) `* set jsonExample $.store.book[0].something = 13` - it is working

2) `* set jsonExample $..book[0].something = 13` - it is working

3) `* eval jsonExample.store.book[0].something = 13` - it is working

**BUT**

1) `* set jsonExample $..something = 13` - it is **NOT** working

2) `* eval jsonExample..something = 13` - it is **NOT** working

I understand that `set` is not working with wildcards (`$[*].foo` or `$..foo`). But are wildcards working with eval? If yes, how? Please example based on file `jsonExample` above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you are so concerned with this. Wildcards will not work for *updating* JSON. It is that simple.

And one more thing, `eval` will work with pure JS only. Json-Path is *NOT* pure JS.

Maybe this will explain it more clearly.

If `* set jsonExample $..book[0].something = 13` is working please assume that it is a BUG. Do not rely on it. It may work in this case because the code is resilient as far as possible. But it may not work in other cases or in future versions of Karate.

All the below will work:

```
* def jsonExample =
"""
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "something": 12.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
"""
# all these will work
* set jsonExample $.store.book[0].something = 13
* match jsonExample.store.book[0].something == 13

* set jsonExample.store.book[0].something = 14
* match jsonExample.store.book[0].something == 14

* eval jsonExample.store.book[0].something = 15
* match jsonExample.store.book[0].something == 15
```

I really hope this makes it clear !!

Comment: Okay, I understand that wildcards is not working for updating JSON. Thank you very much. But if you can explain why it is not working it will be great, thanks. I suppose it would be amazing if wildcard/xpath would work for updating JSON. With this functionality we dont need to write a long path, only exact place what we need.

Comment: @cheparsky you can read the code and get the explanation, feel free to contribute the fix also ^_^ https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/JsonUtils.java#L247