# How to deserialize json payload passed to other feature file which accept multiple arguments

Tags: karate

I am sending multiple arguments to .feature file one of the argument is request json payload generated by using karate table. How to iterate through request payload so that post request will get one payload at a time.

```
Scenario: post booking

* table payload
| firstname | lastname | totalprice | depositpaid | 
| 'foo'    | 'IN'      | 10     | true      |
| 'bar'    | 'out'     | 20     | true          | 

#date will calculate using js function in background and baseURL is configured in karate.config.js file

* set payload[*].bookingdates = { checkin: '#(date())', checkout: '#(date())' }
* def result = call read('createrecord.feature') {PayLoad: #(payload) , URL: #(baseURL)}

######################################
createrecord.feature file will have 

@ignore
Feature: To create data

Background: 
* header Accept = 'application/json'

Scenario: 
Given url __arg.URL
And path 'booking'
And request __arg.PayLoad
When method post
Then status 200
```

Here in createrecord.feature file how I can iterate through passed payload so that single payload will be passed to post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple rule you are missing is that if the argument to `call` is a JSON array (of JSON objects) it will iterate automatically.

Read the docs carefully please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

So make this change:

```
* def result = call read('createrecord.feature') payload
```

And `baseURL` will be available in `createrecord.feature` so you don't need to worry about passing it.

Note that this may not work: `* set payload[*].bookingdates` refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54928848/143475

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your suggestion is working fine. Just wondering in case if there is a need to pass multiple JSON payloads to another feature file. How the user has to deal with it. Or does the Karate not recommend to follow this approach. As in the above example `__arg.PayLoad` is passing an entire JSON object due to which post fails.  

Also, `* set payload[*].bookingdates` is working for me. However as mentioned in the answer provided in the above link, relying on this may be not feasible. So I have used 'set' instead 'table'.

Comment: @ShekharPatil any variable in scope is automatically available to called features. but please ask a new question (with a clear example) if needed