# Is it possible to use smth like JsonPath in JavaScript functions to navigate through json?

Tags: json, karate

Here is my test:

```
  Background:
    * url serverUrl
    * configure headers = read('classpath:headers.js')
    * def getId = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' }

  Scenario: Create lead
    * def req = read('classpath:data/leads.json')
    * def fun = function(x, i){ x.id = getId(); return x }
    * def updated = karate.map(req.updated, fun)
    * def deleted = karate.map(req.deleted, fun)
    Given path '/leads'
    And request req
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And match $..updated.length() == [3]
```

Is it possible to replace somehow these rows

```
    * def fun = function(x, i){ x.id = getId(); return x }
    * def updated = karate.map(req.updated, fun)
    * def deleted = karate.map(req.deleted, fun)
```

like

```
    * def fun = function(x, i){ $x..id = getId(); return x }
    * def req = karate.map(req, fun)
```

Do we have smth that allows easy navigation by json in JS function?

Comment: Here is link to JSON used in example earlier:
https://gist.github.com/kasheylm/9cf75a1427fe7d9574ad5a7c37154c4f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. JsonPath does not work in JavaScript. You probably need to use a second transform using `karate.map()`. For just read-only JsonPath you can use `karate.jsonPath()` - but sorry, updates like this are not possible.

Refer this other answer for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54925754/143475

Comment: Thanks in any case.